# How to install ubuntu networking

Tags: installation, networking

I installed ubuntu server when I was not plugged into the network. I selected configured network at a later time when it asked about DHCP.

How do I now install the network?

There is no eth0 entry in the interfaces file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-networking-configuration-using-command-line.html)  for basic networking steps on Ubuntu.

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

will list all network interfaces on your server.

Detailed official documentation from ubuntu.com for servers goes [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html)